# Difference between prelude and yesod with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod, haskell-prelude

I'm trying to get my MongoDB working in Haskell. I was using [this tutorial](https://github.com/TonyGen/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md) as a starting point.  When I do these commands in prelude, I get a list of collections:

```
pipe <- runIOE $ connect $ Host "XXXXX.mongolab.com" $ PortNumber 33317
access pipe master <databaseName> $ auth <username> <password>
access pipe master <databaseName> allCollections
```

However, when I try to put that in Yesod Handler, it's not compiling.  I have

```
getActivityR :: Handler Import.Value
getActivityR = do
    pipe <- runIOE $ connect $ Host "XXXXX.mongolab.com" $ PortNumber 33317
    access pipe master <databaseName> $ auth <username> <password>
    access pipe master <databaseName> allCollections
    returnJson $ object ["activity" .= ("abc" :: Text)]
```

The returnJson is really just there to let me know I completed the method. Eventually it will return the list of activities.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `HandlerT App IO'

    Expected type: HandlerT App IO Pipe

      Actual type: IO Pipe

    In a stmt of a 'do' block:

      pipe <- runIOE

              $ connect $ Host "XXXXXX.mongolab.com" $ PortNumber 33317
```

So what is the difference between Prelude/GHCi and my Yesod code being built by Cabal?

Comment: I don't know much about Yesod, but GHCi runs this command in the `IO` monad, while your Yesod code is apparently running it in the `HandlerT App IO` monad. Try `pipe <- liftIO $ runIOE $ ...`

Comment: I think @Fixnum's comment is actually the answer.

Comment: @Fixnum That seemed to fix that build error. Thanks. If you'll type it up as an answer I'll accept it and get you some points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that GHCi runs your code in the `IO` monad, while your function is in the `HandlerT App IO` monad.  But `HandlerT` is a monad transformer over the `IO` monad, so you can use `lift` to "promote" your `IO` action to a `HandlerT App IO` action. The type of lift is:

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

In your case, `t` has to be `HandlerT App` and `m` has to be `IO`. 
So the correct code looks like this:

```
getActivityR :: Handler Import.Value
getActivityR = do
    pipe <- lift $ runIOE $ connect $ Host "XXXXX.mongolab.com" $ PortNumber 33317
    access pipe master <databaseName> $ auth <username> <password>
    access pipe master <databaseName> allCollections
    returnJson $ object ["activity" .= ("abc" :: Text)]
```

I don't know what your `access` is, so I can't tell whether you need the lift there too or not.

For your special case, there is also `liftIO` which is like `lift`, but lifts straight to IO, not only to the next "layer" in your stack of monad transformers, so you should use it:

```
pipe <- liftIO $ runIOE $ connect $ Host "XXXXX.mongolab.com" $ PortNumber 33317
```

If you want to know more about this topic you should look for "monad transformers."